# Formatting of df.to_latex()

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I want to export a Pandas DataFrame to LaTeX with `.` as a thousand seperator and `,` as a decimal seperator and two decimal digits. E.g. `4.511,34`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[4511.34242, 4842.47565]]),
    columns=['col_1', 'col_2']
    )

df.to_latex('table.tex', float_format="{:0.2f}".format)
```

Ho can I achieve this? If I change the `.` to an `,` in the code I receive `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would format with _ as the thousands seperator and . as the decimal seperator and then replace those with str.replace.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: str.format("{:0_.2f}", x).replace('.', ',').replace('_', '.')).to_latex('table.tex')
```

Gives the following latex:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
{} &     col\_1 &     col\_2 \\
\midrule
0 &  4.511,34 &  4.842,48 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 13):

As of pandas v1.3.0, you can specify the decimal and thousands separators with the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format) object:

```py
df = df.style.format(decimal=',', thousands='.', precision=2)
```

```latex
>>> df.to_latex()

\begin{tabular}{lrr}
{} & {col_1} & {col_2} \\
0 & 4.511,34 & 4.842,48 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The optimal way is to create a new object from the `df.style` call. For instance it becomes easier to experiment with different style options.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it works with:

```
import locale
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:n}'.format

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[4511.34242, 4842.47565]]),
    columns=['col_1', 'col_2']
    )

df.to_latex('table.tex')
```

But I guess there is a better answer which works only for the exported df!

Answer (score 0):

### Round and convert contents to string

I found it simplest to apply rounding and then convert to strings to avoid zero-padding:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.2345, 2.3456]})
df = df.round(2).astype(str)  # round and convert to string
df.to_latex('table.tex', index=False)
```